# Java boolean query

Tags: java, boolean

I want to take user input in the console such as "keyword1 and keyword2" or "keyword1 and (keyword2 or keyword3)"

Then I want to interpret that and convert it into booleans to query the keyword in an array.

It would have to handle "and","or" and "()" brackets.

I would rather not use a third-party library for it but if there is no easy way I'll take that. I started looking into Lucene but it seems complex for my needs and I want to be able to query an array instead of a document.

Edit: Note I am rather new to programming so simpler solutions are preferred.

Comment: You should probably google for "parser generator" and pick one that you like.  You're using Java, so ANTLR might be a good choice.  Or you can write your own; recursive-descent parsers aren't too hard to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a parser, but you could consider using the java compiler itself if you wrapped the input in code that would make a valid class.

Comment: Is there one in the default classes or should I use one like Lucene?
What do you mean "wrapping the input in code" ? Do you have an example. I'm a bit of a noob :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use compiler of compilers like [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/). It can produce java code than parse expressions with your own grammar and interpret it. In that case you shouldn't use external libs.

[There is](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-cooltools.html?page=3) example of arithmetic calculator on JavaCC.